# How do I open my perspective on first launch after the user installs my Eclipse Feature

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I'm building Eclipse plugins and delivering them via a p2 repository as an Eclipse Feature.

One of my plugins contributes its own perspective via the org.eclipse.ui.perspectives extension point, and it works fine.

Everything is running smoothly.

But what I really want is for my perspective to open when the user first launches his/her Eclipse after my feature is installed.  And then on the second launch, this behavior goes away.  I don't want to annoy the user by opening my perspective every time they launch Eclipse.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You can open new perspective programmatically on your plugin startup. See "Opening a New Perspective" section in this [Eclipse Corner article](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/using-perspectives/PerspectiveArticle.html).

Comment: Yes, the article you linked to seems to cover everything about creating, contributing, and opening a perspective, but it doesn't mention how to only open a perspective on the first launch.  I'm looking for similar behavior that the Welcome Screen of Eclipse uses, in the way that it only shows up on the first launch of Eclipse, and on the first launch after a new feature is installed (if that feature contributes to the Universal Welcome Screen).  I could probably hack a way around to do this pretty easily, but I'm looking for the "Eclipse Way" to do it if it actually exists.

Comment: You programmatically open perspective and then save a flag  that perspective has been opened once in your plugin preferences. Next time you check that flag on startup and skip this step if flag is already set.

Comment: I've thought of that, but wanted to try to stay away from reading and writing 'flags' in preferences, since preferences are workspace related. I finally found this jewel...`PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getIntroManager().isNewContentAvailable()`This tells me when new content is installed, but it doesn't tell me what that new content is, so I'm afraid that if some other feature gets installed, then this code will return true again, and trigger my code that shows my perspective to run again. I've seen some Eclipse plugins do this, so I'm going to track down that code and see how they are doing it.